# How to create flat terrain geotiff for area of interest

Tags: qgis, cesiumjs, terrain, flat

My goal is to create own assets for Cesium Ion (https://cesium.com/docs/tutorials/getting-started/) in certain areas. Thus, I am looking for a way to create .tiff files, that contain flat terrain data information for certain areas of interest (my case: flat airport environments).

QGIS looks like possible solution to me, but I am struggling a bit with the DEM. Here is what I got so far (outline of airport over google maps):

[image]

Now, I try to "fill" this outline with a constant/flat terrain. Given one lat/lon/alt information in the outlined region, how can I create a DEM in .tiff format?

Thank you very much for any hints and tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the tool "rasterize" you could create a raster tif from a vectoriel layer (Raster-->Conversion-->Rasterize).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for...thank you very much!